# File renaming in C++

Tags: c++

I'm translating a piece of code I wrote in Java a long time ago to C++ because I want a .exe I can use directly form windows terminal without the need to install Java.

I need to be able to rename a set of files inside a directory of choice (that's what the code does) and I'm having trouble finding the best approach to follow with C++.

Can anyone give me a hint?
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of C++?

Comment: And if you're not using C++17 yet, then you could use a library. Boost filesystem is a good choice since that's what the standard library version is based on.

Comment: Are you on C++17 or later? If not you will either have to use a 3rd party library like boost, or a platform-specific API like win32.

Answer (score 5):

If you have C++17 or above you can use [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    namespace stdfs = std::filesystem;
    stdfs::path p = stdfs::current_path();
    stdfs::rename(p/"foo.txt", p/"new.txt");
}
```

If not, you could use the C function [`std::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    if (std::rename("new.txt", "foo.txt") != 0)
    {
        std::perror("std::rename");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C++17 or later, you can try [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename).